# Ubuntu Phone o Ubuntu Touch for LG-E615 ......How?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bootloader, devices

Greetings Masters of UBUNTU.
I write to see if is there any way to install a stable version of Ubuntu Phone or ubuntu touch on a device not supported?

The device is a dual sim LG Optimus L5, specifically LG-E615 with a forced android ROM. Currently not starting with this system (stopped working) and is a device that I do not want to try to recover with Android.
I would like to try a great operating system like Ubuntu.

I'm not a developer, so my skills are not as extensive in this area.

I read the information from the site, about how to install the system on the devices but when I try to download the image in the terminal indicates that the device is not in the https://system-image.ubuntu.com server.

It is possible that this consultation is an issue of low importance to a team of knowledgeable as you all, but I still would like to have your help.

Any collaboration that you can give me would be excellent, and I will be truly grateful.

Answer (score 1):

A phone is not a computer (yet), so the first thing that you have to do is *port the system*, following [the appropriate guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/).

It might not be easy, if even not impossible, for your old device, mainly because of the CPU. Ubuntu on smartphones [needs at least](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch#Hardware_requirements) ARM-A7 and 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: Hello dadexis86.
Thanks for your answer, I have tried to do a system port, following the guidance you have provided me. But when trying to install everything you need in my system there has been a failure in the instruction.

I am copying only the last fragment

 u = self.bare_git.var('GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT')
  File "/home/danrre/phablet/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2644, in runner
    p.stderr))
error.GitError: manifests var: 
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

...To be continued...

Comment: to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@Aspire-3050.(none)')

ERROR:phablet-dev-bootstrap:Error while trying to sync repository.

I started this activity without much encouragement because my device does not have the processor you indicated and not enough memory.

I understand it is very difficult to do this and more with my limited knowledge in the area of ​​development; besides that my language is Spanish and not English. 
... To be continued...

Comment: I have to translate everything and not everything is understood in the same way as written in the translation.

Still, I'm grateful for your help, I will not attempt to continue.

Best regards.